# Serve features from PostGIS to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've a PostGIS data table defined this

```
Table Features
{
   id           => INTEGER
   id_user      => INTEGER
   id_topic     => INTEGER
   geo          => GEOMETRY
   geojson      => JSON
}
```

I need to make the geometries available in QGIS with the following requirements:

1. Between QGIS and PostGIS, modifications done on one side have to be synced on the other side.
2. My client using QGIS will be given an URL containing the parameters "id_user" and "topic" to get the features. Those parameters will be used to filter the query and get the corresponding geometries from the PostGIS table.
3. As security, the client will not be able to modify the parameters to get content that he is not allowed to see.
4. Direct connection to the database from QGIS is not possible. We have to go through a map server or an API
5. If a WFS-T has to be used, it must be done with a map server.

The global architecture to be set up is still not really clear for me. My main problem here is how to filter the query to get only features from the specific id_user and id_topic in a secure way?

For information, I have an ASP.NET CORE web environment that could be used as proxy. The number of id_user and id_topic is larger than 100000.

Comment: MapServer tag is specific to https://mapserver.org/ software

Comment: it seems odd to have geometry and geojson as attributes, as geojson will include your geometry and attributes.   Better to have just attributes and geometry in your table and have your API/service supply the GeoJSON as an output format.  WFS-T seems the way to go rather than creating your own API and OGC API Features doesn't yet do transactional queries AFAIK

Comment: GeoServer or TinyOWS support WFS-T (but not MapServer)